# Can I issue a build warning when a someone uses a certain CLR method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there a way to mark method `Guid.NewGuid` usage in code with warning? I would like to relpace all usages with custom implementation and it is unwanted for me to use `Guid.NewGuid` in my future code

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: It is any code that uses `Guid.NewGuid`.

Comment: Tricky... If you where using your own method it would be easy.

Comment: You can't mark already built-in methods as obsolete/depreciated, given that's what you want to do.

Comment: @Adriani6: a custom build rule would help, although I am not sure VS is capable of that, or if it is, it might be a hard nut to crack.

Comment: @Liam I have already replaced all usages of `Guid.NewGuid` but I would like to prevent it in future

Comment: @ThierryV what make you think this question requires code?

Comment: @Liam sorry, my bad

Answer (score 8):

The modern way to approach this would be to build a [Roslyn Analyzer with a Code Fix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn904670.aspx).

This would allow you to mark all locations where it's used in the error list and provide simple "click to get correct code" conversion.

Of course, as with other answers, it does require you to be using the appropriate tool in Visual Studio. Thankfully, if your "better" guid generation routine is packaged as part of a nuget package, you can put the analyzer in there too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite what you want, but how about a unit test that searches your code files for that string? A future developer wouldn't see a warning straight away, but a gated check-in would catch it.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to do this. FYI if you owned this class you could use the [`ObsoleteAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) but you can't change the CLR class

**Also** `Guid` is a `struct` so it's `sealed` (well actually it's a struct but it is effectively sealed). If it was a normal `class` you could override the method. But this isn't going to be possible with `Guid`. **Also** this is a `static` method and can't be overridden. So, yeah, there are lot's of reasons why this isn't going to be possible.

Your best bet to prevent this would be to implement a Visual Studio add in, something like [StyleCop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChrisDahlberg.StyleCop) or to add a rule into your checkin/automatic build script to check for this and prevent the build if it includes the offending code.

If you don't build automatically then I'd recommend you look into continuous integration tools like Jenkins,Team City, etc.

Comment: Even if it were not effectively sealed, you cannot override static methods.